# Symfony 2 FOS_Userbundle promoting users

Tags: symfony

How can I promote a user to ROLE_ADMIN in FOS_User_Bundle using phpmyadmin?

I am running mamp and can't get the MB function to work properly, so I just want to promote the user directly in the database. There's a field called roles, comment: (DC2Type:array), content a:0:{}.

Comment: It's just a serialized array. Dump one out in a test script and stick that in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what `roles` looks like when only ROLE_ADMIN is granted:
`a:1:{i:0;s:10:"ROLE_ADMIN";}`.

For reference, this is what it looks like with an additional role:
 `a:2:{i:0;s:10:"ROLE_ADMIN";i:1;s:9:"ROLE_USER";}`.

Managing roles by directly editing the field in PHPMyAdmin is going to be annoying and prone to error, though. You should either use `php app/console fos:user:promote`. Or, since it looks like it's just a serialized array, you could write a quick script to update the field.